# How to calculate multiplication of each row and show it with jquery

Tags: jquery, multiplication

I have a form where I want to calculate multiplication of field with class `.val` with `.unit` and display it in the field with class `.ad-price-item` in each row. How could I do that with jquery?

My form has lots of rows that can be added or removed:

```
<div class="row">
<input name="datarows[1][radif]" class="uk-form-width-large uk-text-center" value="1" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][code]" class="uk-form-width-large" placeholder="کد کالا" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][name]" class="uk-form-width-large" placeholder="نام کالا" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][value]" class="uk-form-width-large val" placeholder="مقدار" type="number">
<input name="datarows[1][unit]" class="uk-form-width-large unit" placeholder="واحد" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][unitprice]" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money" placeholder="قیمت واحد" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][price]" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money ad-price-item" placeholder="قیمت کل" type="text">
</div>


<div class="row">
<input name="datarows[1][radif]" class="uk-form-width-large uk-text-center" value="2" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][code]" class="uk-form-width-large" placeholder="کد کالا" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][name]" class="uk-form-width-large" placeholder="نام کالا" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][value]" class="uk-form-width-large val" placeholder="مقدار" type="number">
<input name="datarows[1][unit]" class="uk-form-width-large unit" placeholder="واحد" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][unitprice]" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money" placeholder="قیمت واحد" type="text">
<input name="datarows[1][price]" class="uk-form-width-large ad-money ad-price-item" placeholder="قیمت کل" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) functions:

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).find('.val').val() * $(this).find('.unit').val();
    $(this).find('.ad-price-item').val(value);
})
```